# is there way to print pdf from html document

Tags: html, pdf, printing, activex

is there way to print pdf from html document using activex objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PDFCreator API: http://www.pdfforge.org/forum/open-discussion/3063-api-sdk-pdfcreator

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless the client has a pdf printer you can't create pdfs on the client machine using HTML/Activex objects.

Comment: I am not creating PDfs here, just want to show print dialog to print a PDF file when a link is clicked.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. What would the button do ? Will it call the server function which would push a pdf or invoke the user printing prompt from where he can select a printer ?

Answer (score 0):

Install a free PDF Creator like pdf995 printer drivers, after installing open your application  now select print option from Browser File menu > select the pddf995 printer then click on print, now it will save your html page or any type of page in PDF format.